# SQL Server xQuery return NULL instead of empty

Tags: .net, wmi, xquery

So in this example I'm trying to return a NULL instead of an empty nvarchar for element2 and element3. I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere, or if it's even possible. I know I can check .exists() with a nullif of Case/When, but I'd rather not make that check for the sake of performance.

```
 WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery();
        query.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
        query.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent'";
        query.GroupWithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection collection =
            new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        collection.Add("TargetInstance.SourceName");
        query.GroupByPropertyList = collection;
        query.HavingCondition = "NumberOfEvents > 25";
```

Comment: Not sure where SQL Server fits into this, as the code is WMI-related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you are writing in from your question, but SQL Server has a `NullIf(val, CheckValue)` function.  If you can include that in the sql you pass to the server that should do the trick:

```
   Select NullIf(element2, '')
```

will return a null if element2 is equal to an empty string ('')

Comment: I've not heard of NullIf, but it seems like isNull would have the same functionality.

Comment: This works great, because if it doesn't match, it returns the value of the xquery instead of null. Excellent, I ruled out nullif too soon.

Comment: @Sonny Boy,   IsNull(a, b) returns b if a is null,   NullIf(a, b) returns Null if a = b