# In an SQL XQuery result set, is there a way to make the "value" operator return null on missing elements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

When getting values out of xml attributes, using the xquery value operator, missing attributes are returned as null. Is there a way to do the same thing without resorting to `CASE WHEN N.exists('path')=0 THEN NULL ELSE n.value('path') END`?

This SQL:

```
DECLARE @val xml
SET @val = '<records>
  <record attrval="attrval">
    <stringvalue>some value</stringvalue>
    <intvalue>1</intvalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <intvalue>1</intvalue>
  </record>
  <record>
    <stringvalue>another value</stringvalue>
  </record>
</records>'

SELECT N.query('stringvalue').value('/', 'varchar(100)') AS stringvalue,
       N.query('intvalue').value('/', 'int') AS intvalue,
       N.value('@attrval', 'varchar(100)') AS attrval
FROM @val.nodes('//record') as T(N)
```

Results in:

```
[stringvalue]       [intvalue]  [attrval]
some value          1           attrval
                    1           NULL
another value       0           NULL
```

And I would like to get:

```
[stringvalue]       [intvalue]  [attrval]
some value          1           attrval
NULL                1           NULL
another value       NULL        NULL
```

Without doing:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N.exists('stringvalue')=1 THEN N.query('stringvalue').value('/', 'varchar(100)') ELSE NULL END AS stringvalue,
       CASE WHEN N.exists('intvalue')=1 THEN N.query('intvalue').value('/', 'int') ELSE NULL END AS intvalue,
       N.value('@attrval', 'varchar(100)') AS attrval
FROM @val.nodes('//record') as T(N)
```

Note that in this case I can't just use attribute values because there is a limit on the length of the attributes imposed by SQL Server and some of my data exceeds that.

Also, there is a related question but the answer is not applicable because I need to distinguish between empty and missing: [SQL Server xQuery return NULL instead of empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868385/sql-server-xquery-return-null-instead-of-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT N.value('stringvalue[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS stringvalue,
       N.value('intvalue[1]', 'int') AS intvalue,
       N.value('@attrval', 'varchar(100)') AS attrval
FROM @val.nodes('//record') as T(N)
```

Comment: Sweet. That's it. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
   SELECT NULLIF(N.query('stringvalue').value('/', 'varchar(100)'),'') AS stringvalue,
       N.query('intvalue').value('/', 'int') AS intvalue,
       N.value('@attrval', 'varchar(100)') AS attrval
   FROM @val.nodes('//record') as T(N)
```

Using NULLIF ( expression , expression ) where the first expression is the expression returned from the data and the second is the expression to compare it to and if equal, it will return a NULL.

Comment: That was the solution in the linked to question that I said didn't work because I needed to distinguish between empty string / 0 and NULL.

Comment: I apologize for missing that. I'm glad you got the answer you needed.

Comment: As luck would have it, CStroliaDavis, your answer solved my problem perfectly :) Many thanks!